# What is the best practices (business optimal) for localization of a website?

Tags: localization

For a website like a marketplace or similar, what is the best approach for localization if majority of the content is in one language, but some user-generated content is in other languages?

There are so many approaches to this that I am getting confused, I am interested in the most cost-effective business optimal approach for this.

Some typical approaches;

- Website in one language, accept content in many languages
- Website in one language, only accept content in one language (reject other content)
- Website in one language, content in the same language by translating to main language if content is not main language
- Website in multiple languages, content is outputted as is for each localized version of the website, that is, content is duplicated for each language version of the website
- Website in multiple languages, content belongs to the same language version of the website as the contents language is. That is, english content for english version of the website, german content for german version fo the website and so on.
- tld vs subdomain vs directory for localization?

Comment: What approach is most optional for ***your business*** we cannot tell you. It depends on who your site is targeting and what the goals are.

Comment: I feel that this question isn't really programming centric (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Maybe you should ask over at  User Experience (http://ux.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, this is not really a technical question so is probably not the best fit here.

However, I will say that, if you are providing a service that has clients/users from different countries and different languages, basic politeness alone would dictate that you provide a website that can adapt to the client's language.

The content provided by the users in their own language should at least have an automated translation link (e.g. Google Translate).

If you don't do both of these things, you are locking segments of your possible audience out.

You also need to consider legislation. If you are providing services in some countries, it is mandated that you provide a number of base languages.

Comment: Ugh! Please, no Google Translate, it's just horrible. And it often introduces mistranslations that make it worse than keeping the site in English.

Comment: @Clafou: Clearly any automated translations come with a health warning! However, when did you last try it? I've found that, in the last couple of years, it really has got a lot better. So much so that the translations are now understandable rather than hilarious! In any case, it is still generally better to offer the capability rather than lock users out of your system (effectively) - give them the choice, they can decide not you.

Comment: I work in a place where the culture is to frequently use Google Translate to localize bits of Web UI. I'm the only native speaker of one of the languages that gets butchered this way, and believe it, it's still not appropriate. Of course it all depends, if the source language is unambiguous then it's often OK. We also have a mobile app that was translated this way, and although I don't speak Spanish, apparently the "Back" navigation button is translated as the Spanish word for someone's back. In cases like these (short pieces of text), machine translation still can be hilarious.

Comment: Good point though, on the tradeoff between no translation and a potentially rubbish translation. For some types of content it's OK, for others (such as your homepage), I personally believe it's just too unprofessional, and too "cheap" (I mean, you pay designers to give it a nice look, but you don't even pay a human being to write your copy?)

Comment: @Clafou: You are right and I wasn't suggesting that the *site* should be auto-translated, only that the user entered text should have it as an option. The site itself should always be professionally translated if you want any credibility with your customers.

Comment: Ah I see! Didn't notice that you said "The content provided by the users in their own language". Totally with you on that one then (with a link, as you said, to make it obvious that it uses machine translation)

Comment: No worries - feel free to +1 my answer for making me work so hard!! ;)